# spring batch remote partitioning remote step performance

Tags: spring-batch

We are using remote partitioning in our POC where we process around 20 million records. To process this records, slave needs some static metadata which is around 5000 rows. Our current POC uses EhCache to load this metadata in slave once time from db and put it in cache so the subseuent calls just get this data from cache for better performance.

Now since we are using remote partitioning, our slave has approx 20 MDP/thread so each message listener calls first to get the metadata from db, so basically 20 threads are hitting db at the same time on each remote machine. We have 2 machine for now but will grow to 4.

My question is , is there any better way to load this metadata only one time like before job starts and be accessible to all remote slave?

Or can we use step listener in remote stap? I dont think so this is a good idea, as it will be executed for each remote step execution but needed expert thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up [an EhCache server](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/modules/cache-server) running as a separate application or use another product for caching instead like [Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.org/).  If commercial products are an option for you, [Coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html) might also work.